# VSCode - Turborepo - Automatic import suggestion for local packages misses the main entry point

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, monorepo, turborepo

We recently regrouped several repositories into a single monorepo using turborepo for better code reusability using local packages.

Our folder structure looks like this:

```json
/apps
| /app1
| /app2
/packages
| /package1
| | /some-folder
| | | someHelper.js
| | index.js // Main entry point exporting everything
```

package1 package.json file looks like this

```json
{
  "name": "package1",
  "main": "index.js",
  // Omitted irrelevant properties
}
```

Apps package.json look like this

```json
{
  "name": "app1",
  "dependencies": {
    "package1": "*"
  }
  // Omitted irrelevant properties
}
```

When in the context of an app and I reference `someHelper`, the intellisense import suggestion gives the following:

```js
import someHelper from "<rootDir>/packages/package1/some-folder/someHelper";
```

while I would like it to import like this:

```js
import { someHelper } from "package1";
```

Both imports work, but the second one is cleaner. I just cannot make VSCode to work that way.

I tried different combinations of jsconfig.json path aliases at all levels (apps, packages and root directory) but none ever had the desired effect.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: I'm going through a similar situation, did you find a workaround?

Comment: @HWoo_K maybe my answer below can help you. :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/76867311/780291

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adjusting VS Code's `javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` setting?

`typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier` is also available for TypeScript projects.

[image]

Comment: Since then, the problem seems to have solved by itself (probably by some update). But I'll mark your answer as accepted because I didn't know this setting! Thank you.